# install worklight in eclipse juno

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on a hybrid application so when I try to install worklight in eclipse Juno I followed two methods: the 1st one is searching in the eclipse market and that doesn't work and the 2nd is clicking Help, choose install new software, click on add, enter worklight as a name and the following URL for location: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/, here the problem was that this link doesn't work.

Comment: try this link 
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/

Answer (score 1):

The current MobileFirst Studio release on the Eclipse Marketplace is of v8.0. If you are looking for previous releases of IBM MobileFirst, [you can find additional downloads in the developer center](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/.

In v8.0 the MobileFirst plug-in for Eclipse exposes CLI commands into the Eclipse interface, such as: register application, preview application, open console and a few more ([see the tutorial for more information](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/).

v8.0 requires Eclipse **Mars**.

Note: In v8.0 you create standard Cordova applications using the **Cordova CLI**, and you add the MobileFirst SDK (a set of **Cordova plug-ins**) also using the Cordova CLI. You only use Eclipse if you prefer to use Eclipse is your development environment (to write Java/Script code for adapters).

Also required is the THyM plug-in (available from the Eclipse Marketplace) if you'll choose to use Eclipse to develop your Cordova applications.